# Java Integration Test No Runnable Methods error - Spring Runner

Tags: java, spring, testing, integration-testing

I am trying to write my first integration test. JUnit tests are working fine.

Here is my WebControllerIT.java which is the corresponding integration test for my WebController class:

```
package com.socialinteraction.componenttests;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

import com.socialinteraction.SocialInteractionApplication;
import com.socialinteraction.WebController;
import com.socialinteraction.database.repositories.AppUserRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = SocialInteractionApplication.class,
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class WebControllerIT {

  @LocalServerPort private int webServerPort;

  @Autowired private AppUserRepository AppUserRepository;

  @Autowired private WebController webController;

  private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

  private String createURLWithPort(String uri) {
    return "http://localhost:" + webServerPort + uri;
  }

  @Test
  public void testSetNewAppUser() {

    assertTrue(true);
    assertTrue(false);
}
}
```

I am trying to troubleshoot why my Integration Test is not working, hence the simple assertTrue() methods.

I am currently getting a java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods, when I try and run the test class, that test method of the new integrationTest Gradle task I created.

[image: No runnable methods exception]

Here is my package structure for context:

[image: Project structure]

Lastly, here is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.5.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.socialinteraction'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/integration-test/java')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/integration-test/resources')
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2')
    testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2')
//    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4"
//    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.22'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'org.testng:testng:6.9.6'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'org.testng:testng:6.9.6'
    integrationTestCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.0.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest
integrationTest.mustRunAfter test
```

Any ideas why I cannot run my integration tests? Any input would be helpful, thank you!

Comment: Ran into this sometime back. It was related to junit 5 vs 4 that intellij was using. I changed the junit runner that was used to regular junit 4 and restarted and then this went away.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but probably you are mixing junit4 with junit5. Try using this dependencies:

```
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
}
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api'
```

And remove all junit, assertJ, testing dependencies

Then replace `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`

And `classes = SocialInteractionApplication.class` is probably not needed in that case.